# Make list of non public class

Tags: java

I have a java file in which I have two classes in which one is public and another is default like this -

```
import java.util.List;

public class TaskAnswers {


    private float ratings;
    private List<Image> imageList;

    public float getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(float ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }


    public List<Image> getImageList() {
        return imageList;
    }

    public void setImageList(List<Image> imageList) {
        this.imageList = imageList;
    }

}

class Image {
    private String image;
    private String caption;

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }

    public void setCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }

}
```

I want to make a `list` of `Image` class type in another class. And when we write like this than that java file is called as what?

Comment: You simple write `List<Image> list = new ArrayList<>();`, what's the problem?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Nope, it's package protected

Comment: @NwDx In `TaskAnswers` it's valid, I was referring this class.

Comment: @MarounMaroun He wrote "...in another class." So, maybe outside of this package or class at all.

Comment: @NwDx `TaskAnswers` *is* another class. When OP clarify his question I'll comment accordingly.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ya outside this package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java only allows one public class per source file.  Try making the `Image` class public and you will get compiler errors.  You need to call the file `TaskAnswers.java` since it is a requirement that the name of the source file match the name of the *public* class contained in that file.

As user @NwDx mentioned the `Image` class is package protected, which means you will only be able to instantiate it from other Java classes that share the same package.  If you need to access the `Image` class in a separate package, it would be a better design choice to move it into its own `public` class file rather than making it an inner class.

And the code example you posted in your original problem looks just fine.

Comment: You can have public classes in one file. but those classes must be inner ( inner static or just inner) to the one public class.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the class Image in other packages, you have to make it public, but in this case you need to move it to an inner class of TaskAnswers or make an own class (file).

```
public class TaskAnswers {


    private float ratings;
    private List<Image> imageList;

    public float getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(float ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }


    public List<Image> getImageList() {
        return imageList;
    }

    public void setImageList(List<Image> imageList) {
        this.imageList = imageList;
    }



    public static class Image {
        private String image;
        private String caption;

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public String getCaption() {
            return caption;
        }

        public void setCaption(String caption) {
            this.caption = caption;
        }

     }
}
```

For more information please look in the [Java Nested Classes Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: He should probably make it a public class in a separate file if he needs it outside the package as inner classes were created for instances where they are closely associated with the outer containing class (and not in another package).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Full ack. But btw I think "Image" is not a good name for a new class since AWT already got one (I know in another package/namespace). This sounds to me like a "CaptionImage". But this is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Image class is called as `utility class` and TaskAnswers is called as `functionality implementation class` you can use it in following manner and you are using the concept of `high cohesion`

```
List<Image> list = new ArrayList<Image>();
```